# Fill combobox items in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with items in text file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I want to use a text file as my data source to fill in the items for each of my combobox items in my combobox column of the datagridview.  The column has 16 rows with all the comboboxes to be identical.  I have created the text file as a resource in my project and populated it row by row with the items that I want for my combobox items. For code, here is what I have so far:

```
Dim unitsColumn() As String
    unitsColumn = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("engUnits.txt")
```

Can someone please get me started from here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

datagridview1ComboboxColumn.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("File path of text file")

This appears to work.  That was easy.